# onChange doesn't work with react and select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, onchange, jquery-select2

I am using jquery select2 to make a selectbox. (Also new to react) I want to call a function when the data inside the multiple selectbox is changed. onClick and onBlur work as expected but onChange doesn't do anything. I think the issue has to do with how react renders it. If I add on the onChange effect after the component has rendered it works `$('#additional-filters-dropdown').attr('onChange', 'console.log("test")')`
.onChange also works how I want in native html without react. And onChange works if the react element is an input field instead of select so I have no idea why they don't all play nice together.

**React Component**

```
var product_selections = React.createClass({
   handleChange: function() {
      console.log("Selction has been changed!");
   },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className='row'>
               <br/>
               <label htmlFor='product-dropdown'>
                  Product
                  <br/>
                  <select className='js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control' id='product-dropdown' multiple='multiple' onChange={this.handleChange}>
                  </select>
               </label>
           </div>
        );
    }
});
```

**Jquery Select2**

```
$('#product-dropdown').select2({
    data: [1,2,3,4]
});
```

**app_main.js**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
ReactDOM.render(<ProductSelections/>, document.getElementById('product-selection-container'));
```

Anything that can point me in the right direction is helpful.

Comment: i believe on change should be given to option instead of select

Comment: With select2 there isn't an option element to the multiselect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onChange event is not triggered when the value is updated by javascript. In this case Select2.

When using jQuery with react you should try to keep the plugin set up contained inside the component.

Then you can try something like this using the react `componentDidMount` event:

```
var product_selections = React.createClass({
   handleChange: function() {
      console.log("Selction has been changed!");
   },

   componentDidMount: function(){
       $(this.refs['mySelect']).select2({
           change: this.handleChange
       });
   },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className='row'>
               <br/>
               <label htmlFor='product-dropdown'>
                  Product
                  <br/>
                  <select ref='mySelect' className='form-control' id='product-dropdown' multiple='multiple'>
                  </select>
               </label>
           </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately select2 no longer allows the "change" option:

https://select2.org/configuration/options-api

It would need to use 

`.on("change", function (e) {`

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for posting to such an old question, but I came here from Google trying to solve the same problem. Here's an updated example that is working for me:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class EditPhoneNumberContainer extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        let s = $(".editPhoneLocationSelect");
        s.select2({
            placeholder: "Select an option",
            allowClear: true
        });
        s.on("change", this.props.onSelect);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="ibox-title">
                    <h5>Edit Phone Number</h5>
                </div>
                <div className="ibox-content form-horizontal">
                    <select className="select2 form-control required editPhoneLocationSelect">
                        <option></option>
                        <option>Tester</option>
                        <option>Tester</option>
                        <option>Tester</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default EditPhoneNumberContainer;
```

And then you would render it like this:

```
<EditPhoneNumberList onSelect={this.numberSelected.bind(this)} />
```

numberSelected is a function that should handle the selected item.